# get index in set for each element of subset

Tags: java, collections

**Suppose I have:**

```
String[] superArray = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
String[] subArray = new String[] { "b", "e"};
```

**Question:** *What is an elegant way to get index in `superArray`for each element of `subArray`?*

For instance, I want to get `[1, 4]` result.

**Updated: [2nd (related) question]**

*How to copy array by indexes?* Example

```
String[] array = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
Integer[] indexes = new Integer[] { 1, 4 };
copyArrayByIndexes(array, indexes); // returns {"b", "e"}
```

Comment: Sets have no index. The elements are unordered. Maybe Set is not the right tool for the job. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @tobias_k sorry, actually I want to do that for two arrays

Comment: Now that makes more sense. Well, what have you tried, then?

Comment: @tobias_k iterate through the whole array, and check the index of each element. Reinvent the bicycle in other words

Comment: You want the result indexes in a new array or just the indexes?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 4):

You can use a List instead which is ordered

```
List<String> superSet = Arrays.asList("a,b,c,d,e".split(","));
List<String> subSet = Arrays.asList("b", "e");
superSet.containsAll(subSet);
List<Integer> indexes = subSet.stream().forEach(superSet::indexOf)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
int[] indexes = new int[] { 1, 4 };
List<String> lookup = Arrays.stream(indexes).forEach(i -> array[i])
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @V_B in that case you could do the same thing but with loops, or you could mention the need for Java 7 in your question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should do yourself a favor and use Lists instead of arrays. You can easily convert one into the other using [`java.utils.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). Lists just have so many more helper methods, have properly implemented `equals` methods, can grow as needed, etc.

Using Lists, you can then implement your two functions like this:

```
public static <T> List<Integer> getIndices(List<T> list, List<T> sublist) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (T t : sublist) {
        result.add(list.indexOf(t));
    }
    return result;
}

public static <T> List<T> copyByIndices(List<T> list, List<Integer> indices) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Integer i : indices) {
        result.add(list.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<String> superArray = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
List<String> subArray = Arrays.asList("b", "e");       
List<Integer> indices = getIndices(superArray, subArray);
List<String> copy = copyByIndices(superArray, indices);
System.out.println(indices);                 // -> [1, 4]
System.out.println(copy);                    // -> [b, e]
System.out.println(subArray.equals(copy));   // -> true
```